# Is it possible to response with http error, that code are variable in java spring?

Tags: java, spring, http, error-handling

I have an Microservice and it gets an response from another. And based on the response I get I need to respond accordingly. I have no complete List of Error code I can receive, so the question is - can I generate error codes on the fly for my own response? From what I saw in spring the responses are predefined in code. I need to be flexible.

For example:

> I receive a 409 I will respond with 409
>
> I receive a 400 I will respond with 400
>
> I receive a XXX code I will respond with XXX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code: (Sample code)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<ErrorBean> validateUser(@QueryParam("jsonInput") final String jsonInput) {
    int numberHTTPDesired = 400;
    ErrorBean responseBean = new ErrorBean();
    responseBean.setError("ERROR");
    responseBean.setMessage("Error in validation!");

    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorBean>(responseBean, HttpStatus.valueOf(numberHTTPDesired));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on such a use case using the following concept. Try to create a generic exception across micro services. Take 2 params in the exception as error message and another one as error code. Throw the exception from the service being called and catch the same exception in the calling service in the rest template  or feign client call.

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

  private String errorCode;

  public MyException() {
     super();
  }

  public MyException(String message, String errorCode) {
    super(message);
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
  }
}
```

--

```
    try {
        return myApiService.getUser();//call to myApiService microservice
    } catch (MyException e) {
        logger.error("Error: {}", e.getMessage());
        throw new MyException(e.getMessage(), e.getCode());
    }
```

Comment: I trie a variant of this on my own, Suddenly it is not a viable solution. The response code of the controllers is not set in this solution. I will get a response with body like {errorCode=400} but the actual response code of the controller would be something like 200

Comment: This is a generic solution in which we can send the response code when ever MyException(or other exception( is thrown from the controller. That response code can be sent through a  global API Exception Handler in the service being called.